# Is it possible to automate functions in Acrobat?

Tags: automation, adobe, acrobat

Is it possible to automate replacing .png files in Acrobat?

I design labels and the template from one manufacturer is only available in .pdf format. In order to change the design (e.g. different names of the same product) for the smaller labels I have to right click, ctrl+r, select the new .png 30-odd times, and that's just in one file! Not only does it take ages, it's driving me mental...

Is there any way of recording a macro or writing a script so I can select the file I want to replace the .png with and have it do all the labels in the file at once?

[image: Example template with placeholder text]

EDIT: [Word template](https://www.flexilabels.co.uk/uploads/product-files/30-rectangle-labels-per-a4-sheet-35-mm-x-45-mm-flexilabels%20template.doc?v=1655540889)
[PDF template](https://www.flexilabels.co.uk/uploads/product-files/30-rectangle-labels-per-a4-sheet-35-mm-x-45-mm-flexilabels%20template.pdf?v=1655540889)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the label manufacturer supplies software and office templates for the labels so here I downloaded 1" circles into WordPad but normally MS office includes suitable templates.

[image]

You simply print the box contents as required, The inputs in Word can be from Word MailMerge, Access Database or via eXcel OLE/CSV outputs.

A very similar method can be used with PDF templates but on downloading an Avery PDF template I did not see similar Input fields. So in Acrobat you would need to add a set to one template. Export the FDF file with the numbers, probably as two lines if thats what you need. Then filling the FDF template as required you doubleclick the FDF file and it imports into the master PDF for "save as" or print as.

The extra work for FDF would only pay dividends for thousands of programable entries and potentially require several alternative routes. It is much simpler to use the MS Word(Pad) version with any convenient import macro.

For PNG imports you could simply use an HTML template and print to PDF (that can be done command line headless if needing to run thousands at a time, Printing the PDF to printer is a different question :-)
Note I have used 0-9 for illustration but you can adjust for all 30 as you wish.

[image]

A rough template could look something like this, there is surplus to your needs but adjust the values as you require, mine are set to A4 no margins.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#page {
    width:795;
    height:1124;
  }
table {
  margin: 0 auto; /* or margin: 0 auto 0 auto */
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  width: 90%;
  padding-top:10px;
}
td {
  width: 20%;
  border: 0px;
  text-align:center
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;   
}
tr {
  border: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="000.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="001.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="002.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="003.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="004.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="005.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="006.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="007.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="008.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="009.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="010.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="011.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="012.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="013.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="014.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="015.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="016.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="017.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="018.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="019.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="020.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="021.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="022.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="023.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="024.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="025.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="026.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="027.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="028.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
    <td><img src="029.png" width="133" height="170"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The template is also provided in .docx format so it is possible to edit in Word rather than Acrobat. Is it better to try that instead then?

Comment: Now I've realised why I didn't use Word in the first place - the label templates are text boxes, not picture placeholders. It's proving impossible to get them to line up in the right place, never mind trying the relative linked image thing :( I don't think I can upload a file on here to show you what I'm up against...